# pprof tells me that getaliasbyname_r() occupied 56% of cpu time?

Tags: c++, google-perftools

I'm using `google-perftools` to profile my program written in C++ and compiled with g++4.5.2. `pprof` tells me that `getaliasbyname_r()` occupied 56% of cpu time! What on earth does `getaliasbyname_r()` do? Why does it take so much cpu time? Is there a way to alleviate this problem? Thanks.
   The compliation flags were: `-O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-deprecated -Wno-sign-compare`. System: ubuntu 11.04.

Sorry for not making the question clear. I didn't directly use getaliasbyname_r() in my code. In the call graph generated by the profiling tool "pprof", I can see the tree "*start-->*_libc_start_main-->main-->..." counts about 44% cputime. Besides this big tree, there is another ioslated single-node tree in the call graph --- getaliasbyname_r. As showed in the graph, it didn't call, nor called by any other functions. I googled this function and was led to http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaliasbyname_r. But that didn't help much. I still have no idea about how getaliasbyname_r() was invoked and why it took so much cputime. Does this question make sense now?

In reply to Adrian: Thank you for your reply. The total run time was about 28 seconds. The profiler samples at rate of 100/sec. So there were about 2800 samples in total. About 1500 fell in getaliasbyname_r(), coming up with a function written by me (caught about 450 samples).

Comment: Why are you using getaliasbyname_r and also asking "What does getaliasbyname_r() do on earth?". Also you program has to spend some time somewhere - why do you care. 56% of 10microseconds isnt exactly a long time?

Comment: First, if you're using `getaliasbyname_r()`, you should have an idea what it does. Second, if you're complaining about something in your code, posting the compiler switches you used without the source code you compiled is meaningless. Third, there's no real question here - you haven't posted a problem, so we can't help you alleviate it. Remember when posting here that all we have to go on is the exact information you provide in your question - we can't see your screen or code from here, and can't read your mind either. The more information you provide in your question, the more chance of help.

Comment: How long did your actual program take to run - again - it has to spend time somewhere - so unless there is a performance problem - I do not see what your question is. Is your program actually slow somewhere and you want to improve performance?

Comment: @AdrianCornish He is not using getaliasbyname_r. That's why he doesn't know what it does. It is, arguably, a profiler bug that google-perftools attributes the time to the wrong function without making it clear that there is no debug information/symbols loaded.

Answer (score 3):

This problem often happens if you don't have symbols for libc6. getaliasbyname_r is exported from libc6, but many internal functions are not, and many of these internal functions are called indirectly by your code and appear after getaliasbyname_r in the binary.

Therefore, when the profiler does symbol lookup it misattributes the time to the wrong function. Oops.

The solution is to install the symbols and then try again.
http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/symbols-on-linux-part-one-g-library-symbols/

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find the `getaliasbyname_r` uses something called `Name Service Switch` which seems to be some remote service (a bit like `DNS`).

Second thing is that the time measured here seems to ba walltime and not the actual cpu usage.

So my guess would be that `getaliasbyname_r` simply waits for the response from some network service and this eats a lot of time and cpu is actually idle most of that time (the last part is not true in a most of operating systems as cpu will just take care of other tasks, but your application is "stuck" in `getaliasbyname_r` untill a response comes back from `NSS`).

Comment: In fact getaliasbyname_r was probably never executed. The problem is with a failure to find symbols and subsequent misattribution of CPU time.